# How to customize Cocos2D page turn effect with back side texture and shadow?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make nicer effect of page turn transition in my Cocos2D based application. There's CCTransitionPageTurn, but I'd like to add custom texture on back side and dynamic shadow, so it would look more realistic. I'd like to get something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vOYvaNhSHw (page turns at 0:08).

There's a good discussion on how to set up solid color for CCTransitionPageTurn
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15523, but there's no answer to my question.

Does anybody know solution for that?